# How to display "Fetching data" text to user while controller code is fetching data from API?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, progress-bar, loading

My controller has an action method that looks like this:

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @plan = Plan.new

    # This API takes a long time, around 6 seconds
    @plan_data = API.get_relevant_data(current_user)

    respond_to :html
  end
end
```

When a user click 'Create plan' button, it will reach this `new` action and when it gets to API.get_relevant_data, it takes 6 seconds to finish, I want to display 'Fetching data' to the user while this happen.

How do I display that in the HTML page that the user see in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `ajax` here.

Rather than using direct `http` request to the `new` action, send an `ajax`. As long as the new action don't respond with data, you will be able to show a loading screen here.